# Error: cannot find symbol class DaggerAppComponent

Tags: android, android-studio, dagger

I downloaded several sample projects from github that use dagger, e. g. [Moxy sample project](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy) (trying to run github-sample) but everywhere there is the same error - «cannot find symbol class DaggerAppComponent». I did not make any changes in the projects just downloaded and tried to run them.

Gradle version - 3.1.2
AndroidStudio – 3.3

```
def dagger = '2.7'
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"
```

Does anybody has an idea how to fix it?

Comment: **Clean** & then **Rebuild project** once.

Comment: tried it, didn't help

Comment: maybe clear all your caches. gradle and (especially) android studio can do really weird things with their cache sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the below dependency.

`implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.x'`

`annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.x'`

OR try this

`annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.12'`

Comment: compile is deprecated and should be swapped for `implementation` or `api`. also this dependency is clearly already in the build file.

Comment: Changing dagger version from 2.7 to 2.12 solved the problem! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You are Welcome

Answer (score 2):

This may not be directly related to what the original poster was looking for but posting this answer for anyone looking to solve a similar error. If you have converted some of your classes to Kotlin then use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor` in your build.gradle. It is kind of obvious looking back but took me a while to figure out why I'm getting the `sysmbol not found` error with DaggerAppComponenent without any other details.

Comment: I've lost one hour, until I found this answer... I needed to use the @Bindable annotation in a kotlin file, which required me to use the kapt-plugin, and then I couldn't build the app anymore. Just replaced annotationProcessor with kapt and it worked! Thanks